# Custom keyboard function key in Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, kernel, interrupt

i have built a small COM Port device which on every keypress will generate a a key output in the port.

```
key-1 = 0x31
key-2 = 0x31
FunctionKey1 = 0x90
FunctionKey2 = 0x91
```

so i am trying to update the data received from com port to a text box field.

For achieving that i am trying to generate a keyboard interrupt using(libsuinput).

wow it works.

Isssue:

Now i need have four special keys starts from Function-Key-1 to 4 in the device where i need to perform some special function processing when the key is pressed.i don't want to disturb any of the existing function keys.

so how to enable a new function key say like Fx to perform the action.

need some guidence

Comment: For generating keyboard interrupt i am using  : http://tjjr.fi/sw/libsuinput/